# Find the current in the 23 ohm resistor using Thevenin's theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries, electrical-engineering

[image]

How should one proceed to find Thevenin's Voltage across the 23 ohm resistor?

Comment: Pls do note that i do not want to just get an answer to the question, just a directive or some insight would be appreciated. It's just that i haven't come across a case where the resistor was placed in parallel to a current source.